# HERE-API FindSequence Error: "constraint before: must refer to a different waypoint"

Tags: here-api

I'm using the FindSequence API to optimize a route with multiple waypoints.

```
START -> destination1 -> destination2 -> ... -> destination9 -> destination10 -> END
```

Simple optimization is working as expected. But as soon as I start adding `before:` constraints to the waypoints, it starts failing unexpectedly (works sometimes, but fails most of the time) with the following error:

```
{'errors': ['constraint before: must refer to a different waypoint Error ID: '
        '2832b49e-a19b-4703-ac8b-c1bb8dd1effd'],
 'processingTimeDesc': None,
 'requestId': None,
 'responseCode': '400',
 'results': None,
 'warnings': None}
```

My Payload is:

```
{'app_code': 'REDACTED', 'app_id': 'REDACTED', 
'start': '19.23234,72.23234', 
'end': '19.23234.23234', 
'mode': 'fastest;car;traffic:disabled;', 
'departure': '2018-08-30T05:49:58+00:00'
}
```

with waypoints as follows:

```
&destination0=19.0494607,72.82537809999997;before:destination10;
&destination1=19.0721489,72.83006410000007;before:destination10;
&destination2=19.087006,72.83803060000002;before:destination10;
&destination3=19.0790565,72.83579420000001;before:destination10;
&destination4=19.0947793,72.83986809999999;before:destination10;
&destination5=19.12734099999999,72.844066;before:destination10;
&destination6=19.1377862,72.82604549999996;before:destination10;
&destination7=19.1385826,72.82376950000003;before:destination10;
&destination8=19.1383236,72.82696869999995;before:destination10;
&destination9=19.1365928,72.8279202;before:destination10;
&destination10=19.0512729,72.82387169999993
```

Here's the complete url (just replace values for APP_ID and APP_CODE):

```
https://wse.api.here.com/2/findsequence.json?app_code=REDACTED&app_id=REDACTED&start=19.23234%2C72.23234&end=19.23234%2C72.23234&mode=fastest%3Bcar%3Btraffic%3Adisabled%3B&departure=2018-08-30T05%3A49%3A58%2B00%3A00&destination0=19.0494607%2C72.82537809999997%3Bbefore%3Adestination10%3B&destination1=19.0721489%2C72.83006410000007%3Bbefore%3Adestination10%3B&destination2=19.087006%2C72.83803060000002%3Bbefore%3Adestination10%3B&destination3=19.0790565%2C72.83579420000001%3Bbefore%3Adestination10%3B&destination4=19.0947793%2C72.83986809999999%3Bbefore%3Adestination10%3B&destination5=19.12734099999999%2C72.844066%3Bbefore%3Adestination10%3B&destination6=19.1377862%2C72.82604549999996%3Bbefore%3Adestination10%3B&destination7=19.1385826%2C72.82376950000003%3Bbefore%3Adestination10%3B&destination8=19.1383236%2C72.82696869999995%3Bbefore%3Adestination10%3B&destination9=19.1365928%2C72.8279202%3Bbefore%3Adestination10%3B&destination10=19.0512729%2C72.82387169999993
```

How do I go about solving this, as this is the major usecase for our business. Our delivery routes absolutely needs to take into consideration a partial sequence among the waypoints. Any help would be GREATLY appreciated! ^_^

Answer (score 1):

thank you for bringing this to our attention. We discovered an issue in WSE with the "before:"-constraint if the number of waypoints exceeds ca 8 (might depending on the actual parameter settings.). Issue is fixed and will go to CIT this week, to PRD probably by the end of next week.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Although we did move on to using OR-Tools for our requirements, we'd still love to give HERE waypoint optimization another shot! Will be testing this out next week :)